# Get the outer HTML of a DotNetBrowser DOMElement

Tags: c#, dotnetbrowser

The DotNetBrowser DOMElement has an InnerHTML property but doesn't have an OuterHTML property.

Is there a way to get the html of the entire element and its children?

I thought ToString() might do it but it returns empty.

Comment: There are different versions of the DOM (Element1, Element2, Element3, Element4, Element5) and sometimes you need to cast to other types to get additional info.  Check the library you are using to see the versions.

Comment: @jdweng can you point me at the documentation that covers IHTMLElements? It doesn't looks like they are public interfaces in DotNetBrowser

Comment: There is "Microsoft HTML Object Library" (mshtml) and most 3rd party use this library and then write a c++ interface so it can be used in c#.  You can find documentation of mshtml.  I usually don't use the 3rd party libraries and instead just add the mshtml as a com reference.  mshtml is part of windows.

Comment: I suspect you can add the mshtml library to your project and then cast the DotNetBrowser object to the mshtml object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `IElement.OuterHtml` property became a part of DotNetBrowser 2.0 API.

Here is a documentation reference:
https://dotnetbrowser-support.teamdev.com/apidoc/2.0/html/P_DotNetBrowser_Dom_IElement_OuterHtml.htm

This property is writable, and changing its value will replace the element and its DOM sub-tree.

While the element will be replaced in the document, the variable whose `OuterHtml` property was set will still hold a reference to the original element.

In case of any further questions, feel free to contact us at customer-care@teamdev.com

Answer (score 0):

See types below taken from the DOM object

[image]